# Show 0 instead of NaN on my website

Tags: jquery

Hi all when the value is nothing it displays `NaN` but **I want to show it like `0`**.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
var xTruncated = 0;

$(".slider2, .slider").slider({
  change: function(event, ui) {
    $(".slider2").data('prodPrijs2', ui.value);
    $(".slider").data('bierPrijs2', ui.value);
    var x = ($('.slider2').slider('value') / $('.slider').slider('value'));
    var xTruncated = Math.round(x).toFixed(0);
    var uitslag = xTruncated; 
    $('#bier').text(xTruncated);
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check for `isNaN`

```
var xTruncated = (isNaN(x) ? 0 : Math.round(x).toFixed(0));
```

**Documentation:** https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace

```
 var x = ($('.slider2').slider('value') / $('.slider').slider('value'));



 with 


 var x = ($('.slider2').slider('value') / $('.slider').slider('value'))|| 0;
```